# MS Project 2010 XML Export

Tags: xml, ms-project

I have a question about MS Project XML Export. I have a project that, when exported to XML in MS Project, has some strange fields in the XML structure. Under the assignment nodes, there are tags named `<f405040>` and similar ones without any childern tags and no attributes. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project">
<UID>105</UID>
...
<Assignments>
    <Assignment>
        <TaskUID>1</TaskUID>
        <ResourceUID>-1</ResourceUID>
        ...
        <f405040></f405040>
        <f405050></f405050>
        <f405060></f405060>
    </Assignment>
</Assignments>
</Project>
```

These tags cause problems when trying to import the project into third-party applications, probably because they are not allowed according to the XML schema. Anyway, I cannot work with this XML in other applications. And since the other application directly uses the *.mpp-file and creates the XML on its own, I need to get rid of these fields in MSP.

Does anyone know what to do with the *.msp-file in MS Project to get rid of these fields?

Thanks,
Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags represent custom attributes, and they do appear in the XML schema. You won't be able to stop them being generated by MS Project. You can find the schema XSD files in the Project SDK. The Project 2013 SDK can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30435). Google will reveal the SDK download locations for previous version.